# Simple bash questions regarding processes

Tags: bash

I need to achieve the following two things in bash:

```
Give a list of all processes that were started from your terminal
```

And

```
In one command, give a detailed multi-paged list of all processes that
are currently running on the [server].
```

I found out about the [ps command](http://ss64.com/bash/ps.html) but there is no info page
for it on the server I'm working on and I don't completely understand. Help is appreciated.

Comment: You can find [the ps manual online](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ps).

Comment: @Sjoerd This question is not tagged Linux. `ps` on another OS can be a bit different.

Comment: I have yet to find a non-embedded U**x-like OS install with no man pages.  Why not read them and, well, try stuff?

Comment: @MartinJames it's on a school server and for some reason we don't have access to the `man` command. Very stupid of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The complete list of options is available with `man 1 ps`. Flags may differ on different platforms, so there's no substitute for reading your system's man page. However, assuming your version of *ps* uses non-BSD flags, pay particular attention to the `-t` and `-e` options.

Comment: thanks for telling me the needed switches. We don't have access to `man` command..

Comment: @MarioDeSchaepmeester Without knowing which operating system you're on, we _can't_ tell you the switches. `ps` isn't standard to bash -- it's different on every operating system bash ships.